# WithCount do not run subquery condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model Organization which has relation to the Client model:
`public function clients() {  return $this->hasMany(Client::class); }`

Client table and model have two important columns for this query organization_id and status. I need to make a list of organizations with a count of active clients. Here is my query:

`$query = Organization::withCount(['clients as no_of_clients' => function ($query) { $query->where('clients.status', 'active'); }])->groupBy('organizations.id')->get()`

but I get no_of_clients as a sum of all clients, an additional filter where `status = 'active'` didn't run. Can someone explain to me why and how to make it?

Comment: Try function ($q) { $q->... and drop the groupBy(). Is the client.status field value really 'active' or is it a boolean?

Comment: dropping groupBy get fewer results which is not OK to me. And yes, status is text and can be 'active', 'in_progress' or 'inactive'.